# How do I find triple integrals?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

$\int \int\int _w z \,dx\,dy\,dz$; W is the region bounded by the planes $x=0$, $y=0$, $z=1$, and the cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$, with $x \ge 0,  y\ge 0$.

I drew a picture of the cylinder and the planes bounded on it. What exactly is $z$ in the integral?

Comment: Intuitively, you can think of this a the problem of pumping water out of a quarter cylinder shaped tank.  $z$ is the distance you need to pump the water. $(\int z dz)(\iint dA) = (\frac 12 z^2|_0^1)(\frac 14 \pi)$

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You didn't have to do that problem in Calculus 1?

Comment: Not that I recall. This is my first encounter.

Comment: $W$, as given, is not a bounded region.  Do we also have $z=0$?

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic word problem from introductory physics and calculus

Suppose you have a tank full of water. You have attached a pump to the top of the tank to pump the water out.  How much work does the pump have to do?

The shape of the tank is a quarter cylinder.  And the dimensions are 1 unit high, and one unit in radius.  The density of the fluid is  1.  And g is 1.

The work equals the weight of the fluid times the distance you need to pump it.

Anyway to solve this problem without the context of what it might mean.

$\int_0^1 \int_0^1\int_0^{\sqrt{1-y^2}} z\;dx\; dy\; dz$

Now we can plow through the integration.

and It shouldn't be so hard.

Or you can convert to polar

$\int_0^{\frac {\pi}{2}} \int_0^1\int_0^1 zr \;dz\; dr\; d\theta$

and that is even easier.

But, since the limits of $x$ and $y$ don't depend in any way on $z$ you can separate the integration as follows

$(\int_0^1 z \; dz) (\int_0^1\int_0^{\sqrt{1-y^2}} \;dx\; dy)$

and $\int_0^1\int_0^{\sqrt{1-y^2}} \;dx\; dy$ is the area of the cross section of the cylinder.
i.e. $\frac {\pi}{4}$